# How to write a file synchronously in Node Webkit?

Tags: file, node-webkit, synchronous

I am developing a Node webkit desktop application and I need to write a file synchronously, i.e. execute the code lines only when the file has been completely written on the disk.

So, I tried two ways :

```
var fs = require('fs');
tmpFileName = "/the/path/to/my/file";
fileContent = "a big string";
myfile = fs.openSync(tmpFileName, "w");
fs.writeSync(myfile, fileContent);
fs.closeSync(myfile);
```

and

```
var fs = require('fs');    
fs.writeFileSync(tmpFileName, realContent);
```

But none of them are synchronous : they immediately return even though the node JS doc indicates this is the way to do that :  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_close_fd_callback

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe should you try to use writeFile and do the rest of your logic in its callback ?

```js
var fs = require('fs');    
fs.writeFile(tmpFileName, realContent, function(err){
  if(err){
    //Do your error logic
  }
  //Do your post writing logic
});
```

Comment: I just tried that as well and it does not work either.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, this method is working alright ! I tried with a small file and the console.log I added did not show it was working. Working fine with a large file. Thanks grave.e !